# Node.js pipe file to multipart/form-data https request causes next request to time out

Tags: node.js, stream, request, pipe, multipartform-data

I think Node.js v0.12.0 has a bug. Before I submit a ticket I wanted to see if anyone else had any ideas. The stripped down request below succeeds but causes the next request to time out.

```
var reader = fs.createReadStream('file.pdf', {bufferSize: 64 * 1024});
var req = https.request(common.options, function(res) 
{
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    var errors, chunks;

    res.on('data', function (chunk) 
    {
        chunks = JSON.parse(chunk);
        errors = chunk.errors;
    });

    res.on('end', function()
    {
        if (callback)
        {
            return callback(errors, chunks);
        }
    })
});

req.on('error', function(e) 
{
    if (callback)
    {
        return callback(e.message);
    }
});

req.write(file);

//pipe the file and append a closing line
reader.pipe(req, { end: false });
reader.on('end', function() 
{
    reader.unpipe(req);
    req.end(closingLine);
});
```

Comment: `req.write(file);` What is the file mentioned here?